# display the time using time.h header file

Tags: c++, time.h

I want to display the time of invoking a function.
that is

```
void DrawableGameComponent::Update() {
time_t result = time(NULL);
cout << " Updated @ " << asctime(localtime(&result));
}
```

its working fine, it gives the output of date, month, year along with the time. How can I make it to get the time only..
it should display only hours:minutes:seconds.

also the time of invocation should be past as an argument from another member function of another class.that is

```
void Run();
```

Any idea to get it please.

Comment: As for your second part: `void Run(time_t startTime);`

Comment: And as for the first: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/asctime/

Comment: What research have you performed?

Comment: I have tried all the ways. I am just 7 days to C++ and I couldn't figure out this one. The help that i am expecting here is to solve a harder task than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this maybe:

```
char myTime[12];
time_t now = time(0);
strftime(myTime, sizeof(myTime), "%H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
cout << " Updated @ " << myTime;
```

Comment: are you sure? Because it shows me time properly. Look [here](http://ideone.com/ljbsbn)

Comment: oooops i am sorry. It works fine and perfect. Thanks a ton Xonxt! :)